# Clone ubuntu server to another machine using Clonezilla

Tags: server, usb, backup, clone, clonezilla

I am trying to clone an Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation on another machine because I don't want to do a fresh install.

I downloaded Clonezilla on the Ubuntu Server machine and followed the steps to put it on a USB. When I look in the USB there is a folder which I named through Clonezilla called "ubuntu-img".

How do I use the USB now to clone it to the other machine? I plugged it in and made sure that the USB would boot first but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "but nothing happens"? Does it not boot from that USB? ...and if not, what does it do?

Comment: Clonezilla is based on Ubuntu itself, that's why there's an Ubuntu image in the stick. You have to boot the source computer from this stick, tell Clonezilla to clone the entire disk to either directly another disk, or to an image (you need an external HDD or similar device to move it to the other computer then), then either directly insert the cloned HDD into the target computer or boot it also from the stick and tell Clonezilla to restore the image file on the external HDD to the internal disk.

Comment: I did clone the entire disk. By "nothing happens", I mean it doesn't boot from the USB. It just directly boots into the machine's OS. I made sure USB had first boot priority.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting the usb drive in EUFI mode? Have you tried setting the boot flag on the drive? Similarly I have not been able to get clonezilla working :(

A few days ago I did a move from a normal HDD to an SSD using a livecd, gparted and boot-repair. I simply copied the partitions and adjusted the UUID in fstab. I dont suppose this would be a viable solution for your issue?

Comment: I did boot it in EUFI mode. How would I set the boot flag? And no, that wouldn't be a viable option. Thanks though!

Comment: You can do it in gparted.  Find the partition that the drive is supposed to boot from and set its flag to boot.